LWC with lightning-record-view-form fails with previously unseen error: adapter-unfulfilled-error
We've been facing a hard-to-trace issue with an LWC Component with lightning-record-view-form failing to load a record. The browser console prints the following error: adapter-unfulfilled-error (full json of the error log below).
The FlexiPage is in a Console App. There are a bunch of different components on the page using @wire getRecord, getFieldValue and record-view-form as well as standard related lists. The component with the error uses both record-view-form and getRecord (former fails, latter works). It seems that a combination of all those components seems the be the/a problem. When removing some components from the page the error seems to disappear, though I cannot be sure, because it's actually very hard to reproduce the error consistently...
The error seems to only happen for one specific Record Type, but not for all records. Main thing it only happens the first time the record is opened from the results of Global Search. Any subsequent open is without error. Seems that after some time (an hour?) the error happens again for the same record(s) if opened the same way.
We see the same behaviour in PROD and a Full Copy sandbox. It does not seem to matter if Session Settings > secure browser cache setting is on or off. In order to reproduce the problem we have to wait. Logging out and back in the records still open without error.
I even tried to have 2 different browsers (even on 2 different machines) - to see if it's related to LDS cache, which is meant to be specific to browser/app combo. Still the error only happens on the first one who looks at the record.
When "trapping" the with a breakpoint I tried to follow the stack-trace. It seems to start with a navigateToSObject event, then open tab within a Console app, then many things I didn't understand.
Salesforce support cannot help me, because I am not allowed to let them login into our orgs (company policy) and cannot reproduce outside of our orgs. Based on error content and screen-sharing with them they were not able to help.
Log:
{
"name": "Error",
"message": "adapter-unfulfilled-error",
"stack": "Error: adapter-unfulfilled-error\n    at O._errorInternal (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/NUw5mM0F0hsHK-rQn61o8g/apppart1-4.js:1764:29079)\n    at https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/NUw5mM0F0hsHK-rQn61o8g/apppart1-4.js:1764:28880\n    at e.PublicSafety.tryCatch (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/NUw5mM0F0hsHK-rQn61o8g/apppart1-4.js:1667:11605)\n    at O.error (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/NUw5mM0F0hsHK-rQn61o8g/apppart1-4.js:1764:28633)\n    at https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/XqZQemzpOtQq9VdXA2U67g/apppart3-4.js:2428:16158\n    at e.instrumentLuvio (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/XqZQemzpOtQq9VdXA2U67g/apppart3-4.js:2428:16315)\n    at Object.instrumentLuvio (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/XqZQemzpOtQq9VdXA2U67g/apppart3-4.js:2475:14414)\n    at e.Luvio.instrument (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/NUw5mM0F0hsHK-rQn61o8g/apppart1-4.js:1812:55983)\n    at r (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs107/aurafile/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22cac%22%3A1%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22ls%22%3A1%2C%22lrmc%22%3A%22-386269907%22%7D/NUw5mM0F0hsHK-rQn61o8g/apppart1-4.js:1680:2845)",
"userPayload": {
    "schema": {
        "namespace": "sf.lds",
        "name": "AdapterUnfulfilledError",
        "pbjsSchema": {
            "nested": {
                "sf": {
                    "nested": {
                        "lds": {
                            "nested": {
                                "AdapterUnfulfilledError": {
                                    "fields": {
                                        "adapter": {
                                            "id": 1,
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "missingPaths": {
                                            "rule": "repeated",
                                            "id": 2,
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "missingLinks": {
                                            "rule": "repeated",
                                            "id": 3,
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "payload": {
        "adapter": "getRecord__instrumented",
        "missing_paths": [
            "set",
            "valueMap"
        ],
        "missing_links": [
            "set",
            "valueMap"
        ]
    }
}

}
UPDATE: missing log / typos

have you considered it to be a loading order problem? do you have all the required properties initialized when you load record-view-form. And if it's cacheable issue then it makes sense it only happens the first time. So I'd advise adding some lwc:if on view-form to make sure to show it only all parameters are in

if you only pass @api recordId - it's initialized not immediately, so you can use setter for recordId to properly show the form

This is a RecordUiApi problem at the LDS layer. Given that it occurs only once in a period of time, this is likely a server-side timeout/cache miss. You should be able to confirm the problem by opening the Network tab of your browser's Developer Console and then reproducing the problem. I expect there will be a network call on there that's failing, probably a timeout error. A (reacted) snapshot of the failed network call would be illuminating.

@ytiq we only render the record-view-form when recordId is available. Though we de have multiple calls to the getRecord ui API endpoint that each request different fields. I wonder if there could be some conflicts.

@sfdcfox I don't see anything failed in the network tab strangely.

What worked for me was changing the string version of the field(s) I'm passing to the getRecord method from:
const MY_FORMULA_FIELD = [Data_profile__c.MyFormula__c];

to the reference version of the field:
import MY_FORMULA_FIELD = '@salesforce/schema/Data_profile__c.MyFormula__c';
const DATA_PROF_FIELDS = [MY_FORMULA_FIELD];

